# how do I make an image fit in my button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-button

each time I add and image to my button (want to add it below the text) it only shows the top left of the image and adds itself at the top of the button even when I use   *android:drawableBottom* .

here is my XML code :

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="162dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:text="@string/weather_station"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18dp"
   android:background="@drawable/weather"
    android:paddingBottom="120dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    android:id="@+id/weather_station" />
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/weatherman"

    />
```

Comment: Instead of a Button, why not use a ViewGroup (such as a vertical LinearLayout) with an ImageView and TextView as children, then set an onClickListener to the ViewGroup?

Comment: use textview instead of button, then you can set drawable  bottom

Comment: I used button and it worked for one of them, then I tried another one and I still had thesame mistake. actually I am making 4buttons on the page

Answer (score 1):

use `ImageButton` instead of using `Button` and try to scale the image`

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/my_image_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/my_img" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="162dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:text="bUTTON"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape1"
    android:paddingBottom="120dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/cast_ic_notification_2"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    android:id="@+id/weather_station" />
```

how cant it possible even your drawable line out of scop ? try above WORKING CODE

Comment: actually it is in scope, it is just because I pasted without the drawable line and wrote it on stackoveflow myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the below scale type in the xml for fill image in button.

```
android:scaleType="scaleXY"
```

So put this attribute in your xml code.

```
 <Button
 android:layout_width="162dp"
 android:layout_height="200dp"
 android:text="@string/weather_station"
 android:textStyle="bold"
 android:textSize="18dp"
 android:background="@drawable/weather"
 android:paddingBottom="120dp"
 android:scaleType="scaleXY"
 android:paddingLeft="5dp"
 android:typeface="monospace"
 android:id="@+id/weather_station"
 android:drawableBottom="@drawable/weatherman"/>
```